# LeastSquares takes too long

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to design a simple FIR low pass filter with least-square-error approach.
Below is the code for obtaining the impuse response of the filter. It is but to solve the overdetermined matrix.

```
FN = 17; M = (FN - 1)/2; FP = 41; R = (FP - 1)/2;
w = 2\[Pi] Range[0, R]/FP;ak = w < \[Pi]/2 // Thread // Boole;
ck = Cos[Outer[Times, w, Range[0, M]]];
LeastSquares[ck, ak]
```

The LeastSquares keeps running. I'd like to know if there is any numerical solver that can quickly solve the equations. Similar code consumes about just 1s in Matlab. So I guess most probably I didn't go in the correct way in Mathematica.

Comment: If you need numeric, simply change to  `LeastSquares[N[ck], ak]`

Comment: Thanks, that simply solves the problem. It means we need to "numeric" the matrix first, instead of solving it numerically @Acus

Comment: General rule: never mix exact and numeric arithmetic. If your need numeric, make it numeric in the input, otherwise Mma will attempt to find exact (strict) solution.

Comment: @Acus This is good advice, save for one specific case: if your inputs go into a function that has the `WorkingPrecision` option, it's usually best to keep your inputs as exact as possible and let the function handle the precision for you.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit In some cases the opposite strategy is better. For example when starting to solve differential equations I usually rationalize the coefficients (as well as initial/boundary conditions). I think the main goal is to avoid symbolic attempts when they are not needed and force them when they can help numerical algorithm. Mixing both, however, rarely can be useful.

Comment: So, I agree with your statement about WokringPrecision, since NDSolve has it